# "Holds value of property" in Java code

Tags: java, code-generation, comments

I got some legacy code with that caption spread out as comment almost in every field. Also appearing is "`Setter for property xyz`".

Just out of curiosity, which Java tool generated this stubs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I seem to remember the same, but I can't confirm because I don't remember how I did it before.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://svn.atlassian.com/svn/public/contrib/tools/javacvs/trunk/src/org/netbeans/modules/javacvs/FsLog.java) is to a source file for a NetBeans cvs log module. It contains the same captions and comments as in your legacy code. I assume that they used NetBeans itself to write this peripheral module. So I guess the answer is NetBeans.